# Python Optparse module for no argument option implementation

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

I have a script in which i need to restrict running the script without any option
i have tried the following program and i slightly missing somewhere kindly help

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import optparse

path = "/tmp/enable.txt"
usage = "This program will Help you to Enable and Disable Release Management"
parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)

parser.add_option("-e", "--enable", dest="enable", action="store_true", help="This will     enable Release management")
parser.add_option("-d", "--disable", dest="disable", action="store_true", help="This will disable Release management")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

> optionsdict = vars(options)
>
> ```
>  for k,v in optionsdict.items():
>       if v is None:
>       all_none = True
>
>
> if all_none:
>  parser.print_help()
>  sys.exit()
> ```

```
if options.enable:
if os.path.exists(path):
   print "Its already enabled"
else:
   open(path, 'w').close()
   print "Enabled"

if options.disable:
 if not os.path.exists(path):
   print "Its already disabled"
else:
   os.remove(path)
   print "Disabled"
```

Everything works fine only if i run my script without option i needs to tell me --help option with telling enter some option

Only centre part of code is not working am imissing something

Thanks in advance 
Sathishkumar

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer instead of running the whole options this will fix the issue

```
if len(sys.argv[1:])== 0:
  print "Kindly enter some options"
```

Thanks
Sathish